# MERGE SQL code not working correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was wondering if anyone could help.

I have this piece of code in my stored procedure, but the Merge is not working for field Address. Works for the other fields.

I have a source file with all address to be filled to the Source.

The Source contains a field with all addresses. When I run the query the Target Address column fills only one row with the correct address. I can see that there was a Location change in source, the Location with the Address was updated for that one row, but not for the rest of the properties in the table.

```
DECLARE @SQLMerge nvarchar(4000)
SET @SQLMerge=' MERGE '+@RPTblName+' AS target'+
                  ' USING '+@CMTblName+' AS source
                   ON target.VersionEndDate IS NULL AND target.PtyId = source.PtyId

WHEN MATCHED AND NOT (target.Location =source.Location AND target.Price=source.Price 
AND target.PtyCode=source.PtyCode 
AND target.[FloorSpace] = source.[FloorSpace] 
AND target.Address = source.Address)


THEN UPDATE SET VersionEndDate ='''+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),@ReportMonthEND,121 )+''';'
IF @debug=1 print @SQLMerge
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLMerge
```

Comment: Try to execute merge statement directly first (without dynamic sql) and tell us what exactly 'not working' means.

Comment: I have edited my question, with a more detailed explanation. Let me know if it is still not clear.

Comment: Since your `MERGE` statement only contains syntax to update the `VersionEndDate` column, this is totally expected. I'll add SQL-Server to your list of tags - I assume this is SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
DECLARE @SQLMerge nvarchar(4000)
SET @SQLMerge=' MERGE '+@RPTblName+' AS target'+
              ' USING '+@CMTblName+' AS source
               ON target.VersionEndDate IS NULL AND target.PtyId=source.PtyId

WHEN MATCHED AND NOT (target.Location =source.Location AND target.Price=source.Price 
AND target.PtyCode=source.PtyCode 
AND target.[FloorSpace] = source.[FloorSpace] 
AND target.Address = source.Address)


THEN UPDATE SET target.VersionEndDate ='''+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),@ReportMonthEND,121 )+''';'
IF @debug=1 print @SQLMerge
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLMerge
```

Comment: What change did you make? add target. to VersionEndDate? I tried this but it didn't work. Please let me know if you made any other changes, that I didn't spot. Many thanks

Comment: @Camille, I added table alias for referring VersionEndDate.